# adding argument with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have this little problem with argparse :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
#test.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
parser.add_argument('c', nargs='*')
parser.add_argument('cj', nargs='*')

results = vars(parser.parse_args())
print results
```

Now in the command line if I type in : "test.py c 1"

it returns this

> {'cj': [], 'c': ['c', '1']}

but if I type in "  "test.py cj 1"

it returns this :

> {'cj': [], 'c': ['cj', '1']}

I am expecting the second example to return value in the 'cj' key, but it keeps on appears in the 'c' key.

what am I doing wrong ?

cheers,

Comment: try swapping the `add_argument` lines and see the change in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `*` will match everything that comes after it. Since the `c` argument has the first `*` everything that is passed in will end up in `c`.

If you want to store a single item in `cj` and a single item in `c` you could do:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
parser.add_argument('c', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('cj', nargs='+')
```

If what you want is:

```
{'cj': ['1'], 'c': ['cj']}
```

This is because the `+` matches a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues:

- you use positional arguments (they do not start with '-', or '--'), but you provide their names at command line
- you use `nargs='*'` that consumes all arguments that it can